# How to pass SELECT statement result as parameter to function in stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

In my stored procedure I have `SELECT` statements. I want to pass results of those `SELECT` statements to a function as a parameter. Please tell me how to pass parameters to function in SQL Server.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PositionReport                                
AS 
BEGIN 
   (select COUNT(ID) from Submissions where SubmissionStatus = 'Status1') Status1,                    
   (select COUNT(ID) from Submissions where SubmissionStatus = 'Status2') Status2,                    
   dbo.[fnGetTotal](Status1,Status1) Total                             
END
```

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetTotal](@Status1 int, @Status1 int)
RETURN varchar(100) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Total varchar(100);

   SELECT @Total = @Status1 + @Status1
   RETURN @Total                           
END
```

My original stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_GetJobsPositionReport]
    @AccountID int, 
    @Userid int,
    @JobTitle varchar(100),
    @ClientID varchar(8000),
    @ContactID varchar(8000),
    @PageNum int,
    @PageSize int,
    @SortExpression varchar(1000),
    @isExport bit = 0
AS             
BEGIN
   SELECT @sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT distinct ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY ' + @SortExpression + ') as SNo, Jobs.JobNo, Jobs.JobID, Jobs.JobTitle, VendorClients.CompanyName Client, VendorContacts.FirstName + '' ''  + VendorContacts.LastName as ContactName, Users.FirstName + '' ''+ Users.LastName CreatedBy, (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus in(''Submitted'',''Screening'') and InterviewType is null and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) Submitted, (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus not in (''Potential'',''Rejected'',''Attached'',''CandidateWithdrawn'',''Backout'',''Matched'') and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) Active,      
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus = ''Shortlisted'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) ShortListed,                                        
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus in(''Submitted'',''Screening'') and InterviewType = ''Phone'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) PhoneInterview,                                   

                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus in(''Submitted'',''Screening'') and InterviewType = ''Face2Face'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) F2FInterview,                    
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus in(''Submitted'',''Screening'') and InterviewType = ''Web'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) WebInterview,                                       
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus = ''UnderReview'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) UnderReview,                                        

                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus = ''OfferMade'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) OfferMade,                    
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus = ''OfferRevoked'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) OfferRevoked,                    
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus = ''OfferNegotiating'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) OfferNegotiating,                    
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus = ''OfferAccepted'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) OfferAccepted,                    
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus = ''OfferRejected'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) OfferRejected,            
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus = ''Screening'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) Screening,                                                    
                   (select COUNT(SubmissionID) from CandidateSubmissions where SubmissionStatus = ''Joined'' and CandidateSubmissions.jobid=jobs.jobid) Joined,    

                    Jobs.PositionType TypeOfHire,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Jobs.PostedDate, 106), '' '', ''-'') PostedDate,                                          
                    PrimaryIndustry = case Jobs.PrimaryIndustry                                          
                                      when ''Select'' then ''''                           
                                      else Jobs.PrimaryIndustry                                          
                                    end,                                      
                    JobCategory = case Jobs.JobCategory                                          
                                   when ''Select'' then ''''                                          
                                   else Jobs.JobCategory                                          
                                end,'                    

                 select @sqlLinkQuery = 'Education = case Jobs.MinimumEducation                                          
                                       when ''Select'' then ''''                                          
                                       else Jobs.MinimumEducation                                          
                                   end,                                           


                       FROM Jobs WITH(NOLOCK)      
                        INNER JOIN Users WITH(NOLOCK) ON Jobs.UserID = Users.UserID and Users.IsActive=1                        
                       INNER JOIN AccountUsers WITH(NOLOCK) ON AccountUsers.UserID = Jobs.UserID      
                       INNER JOIN CityList WITH(NOLOCK) ON Jobs.JobLocation = CityList.CityID                                                 
                       INNER JOIN JobAssignedUsers WITH(NOLOCK) ON Jobs.JobID = JobAssignedUsers.JobID                                            

                       where Jobs.JobStatus = ''Open'' AND jobAssignedUsers.userid = '+ CONVERT(varchar(9),@Userid)+ ' AND VendorClients.AccountID = '+ CONVERT(varchar(9),@AccountID)+ @strJobTitle + @strClientID + @strContactID +'                   
                   ) as Result'                    

   SELECT @subSql = ' where  Result.SNo >= '+ CONVERT(varchar(9), @boundPageNum) +' and Result.SNo <= '+ CONVERT(varchar(9), @boundPageSize)                                              

   IF(@isExport = 0)                
    BEGIN                
         EXEC (@sqlQuery + @sqlLinkQuery + @subSql)                    
         EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*)TotalRows FROM ('+@sqlQuery + @sqlLinkQuery+')a')                
    END                
   ELSE              
    BEGIN                
         EXEC (@sqlQuery + @sqlLinkQuery)                
    END                     
END
```

Comment: Is it 2005 or 2008 SQL server?

Comment: I was very confused by the question until I looked at the edit history. Seems someone (hi @juergend!) sneakily added parameters to the function call!

Comment: @DavidG: What are you talking about? Nothing was added to the question except formatting.

Comment: @juergend Look at the edit history. Original is `dbo.fnGetTotal Total` and your edit is `dbo.[fnGetTotal](Status1,Status1) Total`

Comment: @DavidG: I guess this is a race condition. The OP and I probably edited at the same time. I only hit the format button on that post and did not enter any character.

Comment: @juergend This is horribly off topic now but... format button?

Comment: @DavidG: I meant code-format-button. I marked the code part and hit the `{}` button in the post editor.

Comment: Why all the NOLOCK hints? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicated data? Is accuracy not important for this query? Here is one of dozens of articles that explains what this hint really does. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change your procedure as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PositionReport                                                                                                             
as                                                                                                                                      
BEGIN 

DECLARE @Status1 int
DECLARE @Status2 int


select @Status1=COUNT(ID) from Submissions where SubmissionStatus = 'Status1'                   
select @Status2=COUNT(ID) from Submissions where SubmissionStatus = 'Status2'                    

SELECT @Status1 as Status1,@Status2 as Status2
       ,dbo.[fnGetTotal](@Status1,@Status1) Total                             
END
```

But I dont think a seperate function is required unless you are doing something more complicated.

Comment: Sorry , Actually my sp is follows. i have given for example.

Comment: I updated my SP, Please check it and give me any suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the select statement it self (as a string) to the stored function, not its result, and run it inside the function.

To run some SQL command from string use:

```
sys.sp_executesql
```

Example:

```
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'select ''Hello world'' as Result'
```